# libcublas issue - tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am very new to tensorflow, struggling on its installation. I use ubuntu 16.04. I obviously installed the Nvidia dependencies.
Whenever I type in:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I get:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
File "/media/as/KINGSTON/SIEC NEURONOWA/NETWORK.py", line 3, in <module>
from keras.models import Sequential

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import activations

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/activations.py", line 4, in <module>
from . import backend as K

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
from .tensorflow_backend import *

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf

File "/home/as/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *

File "/home/as/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/home/as/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/as/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "/home/as/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "/home/as/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

I tried many solutions, but the effect remains the same. Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when installing gputools in R. After hundreds of tries, the command which worked for me is:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so.8.0 /usr/lib/libcublas.so.8.0
```

OR

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcublas.so.8.0 /usr/lib/libcublas.so.8.0
```